# How do I kill unresponsive threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I've been trying to find a way to kill the threads that are unresponsive at the end of this program:

Most of the time the code works, but on certain domains some of the threads will hang, not allowing the program to complete.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

from socket import gethostbyaddr
import dns.resolver
import sys
import Queue
import threading
import subprocess
import time

exitFlag = 0
lines = ''

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.q = q
    def run(self):
        process_data(self.name, self.q)

class Timer():
   def __enter__(self): self.start = time.time()
   def __exit__(self, *args):
        taken = time.time() - self.start
        print " [*] Time elapsed " + str(round(taken,1)) + " seconds at " + str(round(len(subdomains) / taken)) + " lookups per second."

def process_data(threadName, q):
    while not exitFlag:
        queueLock.acquire()
        if not workQueue.empty():
            data = q.get()
            queueLock.release()
            host = data.strip() + '.' + domain.strip()
            try:
                answers = resolver.query(host)
                try:
                    output = gethostbyaddr(host)
                    if len(host) < 16:
                        print str(host) + "\t\t" +  str(output[0]) + " " + str(output[2])
                        found.append(str(host) + "\t\t" +  str(output[0]) + " " + str(output[2]))
                    else:
                        print str(host) + "\t" +  str(output[0]) + " " + str(output[2])
                        found.append(str(host) + "\t" +  str(output[0]) + " " + str(output[2]))
                except:
                    print str(host)
                    found.append(str(host))
            except:
                pass
        else:
            queueLock.release()

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print
    print 'Usage: dnsbrute.py <target.com> <subdomains.txt> (threads)'
    exit()

if len(sys.argv) >= 4:
    maxthreads = int(sys.argv[3])
else:
    maxthreads = int(40)

domain = sys.argv[1]
maked = "mkdir -p logs"
process = subprocess.Popen(maked.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
poutput = process.communicate()[0]
found = []
subdomains = [line.strip() for line in open(sys.argv[2], 'r')]
dnsservers = ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4", "4.2.2.1", "4.2.2.2", "4.2.2.3", "4.2.2.4", "4.2.2.5", "4.2.2.6", "209.244.0.3", "209.244.0.4" ]
threadList = []
numthreads = 1
resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
resolver.nameservers = dnsservers
logfile = open("logs/" + domain + ".log", 'w') 

while numthreads <= maxthreads:
    threadList.append(str("Thread-") + str(numthreads))
    numthreads += 1

print " [*] Starting " + str(maxthreads) + " threads to process " + str(len(subdomains)) + " subdomains."
print

queueLock = threading.Lock()
workQueue = Queue.Queue(len(subdomains))
threads = []
threadID = 1

with Timer():
    for tName in threadList:
        thread = myThread(threadID, tName, workQueue)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
        threadID += 1

    queueLock.acquire()
    for work in subdomains:
        workQueue.put(work)
    queueLock.release()

    while not workQueue.empty():
        pass

    exitFlag = 1

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    for item in found:
      logfile.write("%s\n" % item)

    print
    print " [*] All threads complete, " + str(len(found)) + " subdomains found."
    print " [*] Results saved to logs/" + domain + ".log"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please bear in mind that it is a bad approach to kill threads in whatever language, becuase the resources can be left in an unconsistent state. If you can, try to redesign your program such that the threads will close themselves by checking a boolean value. Anyway, a very good answer from a fellow here on SO:

[Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)